# socket programming addrinfo structure

Tags: c, sockets

In socket programming(I'm on Winsock, if that matters) does the socket type structure member value(i.e. STREAM) have to match that of the protocol structure member(i.e. TCP)? In the documentation of Winsock it says that these are only the possible values, that it implies 'well they don't have to match, necessarily(i.e. STREAM is to TCP, or DATAGRAM is to UDP)'.

If they do not necessarily have to match, under what circumstance will you be able to mismatch them? If they particularly have to match, why specify two structure members when really one value determines the value of the other?

Comment: I see the PROTOCOL_INFO structure at t.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740104(v=vs.85).aspx but can't tell which socket structure you're referring to.  Do you have a link?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737530(v=vs.85).aspx for the `addrinfo` structure.

Comment: I'm referring to the `struct addrinfo`

Comment: There can be many streaming protocols besides TCP, as well as many datagram based protocols besides UDP. If you want to be on the safe side you should specify `IPPROTO_TCP` or `IPPROTO_UDP` in your hint to `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: So is that sort of a headroom for when you want to implement your own protocols, because there is only one specified protocol for each socket type. Because even when it's for future additional library protocol support, I still think specifying only the protocol is all you need(the socktype is sort of implied).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you refer to the `pHints` parameter of `getaddrinfo()`. They strictly don't have to match, but if the combination doesn't make sense, you won't get any results.

But you can set one of them to `0` and only use the other one.